# Excel VBA sort array function

Tags: vba, excel

I've written the function displayed below. It works when I use it in the Sub. This is the first time that I'm trying to write a function. I know this is a noob question however I can't seem to get the function to run. It's probably something about not calling the function correctly or maybe not defining the variables in the function header correctly

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

```
Function SortArray(ArrayToSort As String)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim TempTxt1 As String
    Dim TempTxt2 As String

    For x = LBound(ArrayToSort) To UBound(ArrayToSort)
        For y = x To UBound(ArrayToSort)
            If UCase(ArrayToSort(y)) < UCase(ArrayToSort(x)) Then
                TempTxt1 = ArrayToSort(x)
                TempTxt2 = ArrayToSort(y)
                ArrayToSort(x) = TempTxt2
                ArrayToSort(y) = TempTxt1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Function


Sub CreateUniquesList()
    Dim References() As String
    ...
    SortArray (References)
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code and what is it not doing?  It looks like you're doing comparisons on the same array, when one is larger, switch them around.  Essentially ascending order?

Comment: The function is supposed to sort an array in alphabetical order. Like I said above, this works in the Sub. I've never written a Function before so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement the code as a function. Essentially, the code within the function is identical to the code that was in the Sub, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: You can just make it a Sub since your Function isn't returning anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add parentheses to make sure the parameter is an array

```
Function SortArray(ArrayToSort() As String)
    'your code
End Function

Sub CreateUniquesList()
    Dim References() As String
    '...
    SortArray References 'lose the parentheses
    '...
End Sub
```