# Sort Excel VBA Number and Text Array with FUNCTION

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

If I have values in cell A2=2,4,8,6,12,19,18,23,35,78,101,38,30,205,2
And I want to sort by smallest to largest or largest to smallest in cell B2. then my desired result should be =2,2,4,6,8,12,19,18,23,30,35,38,78,101,101,205 or,Large to small= 205,101,101,78,38,35,30,23,18,19,12,8,6,4,2,2 if I have textvaluse like in A3= WPN/01,AFF/02,PROP/4,ENG/03 Then I want to sort alphabetically my desired result should be in cell B3=AFF/02,ENG/03,PROP/4,WPN/1
[image: sheet is attached]

Comment: See if this helps .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077753/excel-vba-sort-array-function ... and this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152319/vba-array-sort-function

Comment: @NareshBhople sir showing Compile Error in LBound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following function will work for numbers, text and alphanumeric (numbers and text both) strings. Default srtCriteria is set to 0. So, if it is 0 or not mentioned the array will be sorted ascending, else if srtCriteria = 1 then descending.

```
Function SortArr(myString As String, deLmt As String, Optional srtCriteria = 0)
'myString is deLmt seperated string
'srtCriteria is criteria to sort; 0 or nothing for Ascending, Other digit for descending.
Dim Lb As Long, Ub As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim arr, reverseArray
Dim strTemp As String

arr = Split(Trim(myString), deLmt)
Lb = LBound(arr)
Ub = UBound(arr)
For i = Lb To Ub - 1
    For j = i + 1 To Ub
        If IsNumeric(arr(i)) = True And IsNumeric(arr(j)) = True Then
            If Val(arr(i)) > Val(arr(j)) Then
            strTemp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = strTemp
            End If
        Else
            If (arr(i)) > (arr(j)) Then
            strTemp = arr(i)
            arr(i) = arr(j)
            arr(j) = strTemp
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If srtCriteria = 0 Then
    SortArr = Join(arr, deLmt)
    Else
    ReDim reverseArray(Ub)
        For i = 0 To Ub
            reverseArray(i) = arr(Ub - i)
        Next
    SortArr = Join(reverseArray, deLmt)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Milan your doubt is valid.. If a string contains text and numbers it will work in absurd manner for numbers. So editing my answer.. MIX function gives better result.

Comment: Ok Great Sir It worked well.Thanks so much

Comment: Sir If I want to sort by large to small , then where edit in the formula

Comment: edited my answer to reverse the sort.

Comment: Yaa it worked   Nice you're doing nice coding Great. I want to become your Student pls.

Comment: I am student myself... There are many gurus on this platform whom we can follow.

Comment: Ok Sir, But you explain very easily all thing in a very decent manner .Follow you I'm also living in Pune.If needs I can call you Sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210097/discussion-between-milan-kumar-and-naresh-bhople).