# Excel formula in sorting delimited numbers in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im new in excel formulas. I need an excel formula that can sort delimited numbers in a single cell.
Note: I have different lengths of values per cell.

I.g.
349|2|4|11|1|2

Outcome:
1|2|2|4|11|349

Im thinking of reverse concatenating it first then sort it then concatenate it again. But i can't figure it out how to make a working formula for that. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you will ultimately need a VBA solution (in the form of a User Defined Function - UDF) to solve this because each number is separated by a delimiter. If you only had numbers in the cell, see [this site](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1870-excel-sort-numbers-within-cell.html) for some ideas.

Comment: Here is a [UDF Solution](https://superuser.com/questions/705131/sorting-values-within-a-cell-in-excel) that you can use. Just change the split to be on `|` instead of `,`

Comment: See if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60797214/9808063) helps .. I tried it on the given sample, no issues. It works on alphanumeric as well.

Answer (score 1):

This formula solution worked in cell contains numeric value only.

The formula using `Textjoin` and `Filterxml` function of which `Textjoin` available in Office 365 and Excel 2019, and `Filterxml` available in Excel 2013 and later Excel version

Assume your data housed in `A1`

In `B1`, enter array formula (Confirm by pressing Shift + Ctrl + Enter) :

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",1,IFERROR(1/(1/SMALL(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),ROW($1:$99))),""))
```

[image]