# Sort the dates ascending

Tags: excel, vba

I know its basic, but I am new to excel vba and learning, how can I sort a string with csv dates to order ascending from current for example

result = "31-Dec-2020,24-Sep-2020,25-Mar-2021,02-Jul-2020,09-Jul-2020,16-Jul-2020,30-Jul-2020,23-Jul-2020,27-Aug-2020,06-Aug-2020,13-Aug-2020,20-Aug-2020,30-Dec-2021,29-Dec-2022,29-Jun-2023,24-Jun-2021,30-Jun-2022"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is in "A2" then enter in "B2" following formula. Or you can use it in other desired procedure.

```
=SortArr(A2,",",0)
```

Following is the VBA function for "Dates" .. Reference this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60797214/9808063) for numbers and text ..

```
Option Explicit

Function SortArr(myString As String, deLmt As String, Optional srtCriteria = 0)
'myString is deLmt seperated Dates string
'srtCriteria is criteria to sort; 0 or nothing for Ascending, Other digit for descending.
Dim Lb As Long, Ub As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim arr, reverseArray
Dim strTemp As String

arr = Split(Trim(myString), deLmt)
Lb = LBound(arr)
Ub = UBound(arr)
For i = Lb To Ub - 1
    For j = i + 1 To Ub
        If DateValue(arr(i)) > DateValue(arr(j)) Then
        strTemp = arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(j)
        arr(j) = strTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If srtCriteria = 0 Then
    SortArr = Join(arr, deLmt)
    Else
    ReDim reverseArray(Ub)
        For i = 0 To Ub
            reverseArray(i) = arr(Ub - i)
        Next
    SortArr = Join(reverseArray, deLmt)
End If

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks yes for NSE :), the output I am getting is "02-Jul-2020,06-Aug-2020,09-Jul-2020,13-Aug-2020,16-Jul-2020,20-Aug-2020,23-Jul-2020,24-Jun-2021,24-Sep-2020,25-Mar-2021,27-Aug-2020,29-Dec-2022,29-Jun-2023,30-Dec-2021,30-Jul-2020,30-Jun-2022,31-Dec-2020" but I need as per expiry... date column..

Comment: Not sure why you are getting different results. See added image. May be its the date format in your system. Do you want the string to be split into a sorted column?  What is date format in your excel formula bar?

Comment: actually I am passing the string result to the function, not using it as excel function. can it be sorted?

Comment: While the sorting is OK, the Question is expanded with `expiry date column` which is not mentioned in the question, @Kiran WHY ?

Comment: Agree with @Luuk. Kiran, to avoid long chat, please edit the question with the desired result may be with a sample screenshot. Also, instead of entering the sorted result as a string in your excel function, you can mention this "SortArr" function in place of the string in your excel function. Remember, there is [limit on number of characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) we enter in an excel function

Comment: Naresh, the above "result" is output from a function, but I want to format that output to as "02-Jul-2020,09-Jul-2020,16-Jul-2020,23-Jul-2020,30-Jul-2020,06-Aug-2020,13-Aug-2020,20-Aug-2020,27-Aug-2020,24-Sep-2020,31-Dec-2020,25-Mar-2021,24-Jun-2021,30-Dec-2021,30-Jun-2022,29-Dec-2022,29-Jun-2023". .. no excel columns involved here.

Comment: instead of excel column, can u try passing the result to ur function directly, u will get different sort.

Comment: So, instead of A2 in my function you need to mention your function giving this result. In short, wrap your function with SortArr function. .. Like `=SortArr(YourFunction,",",0)`

Comment: Naresh, still getting same output,  this is my function where I am removing duplicates and getting unique output, only need to sort as per expiry `Public Function unik(rng As Range) As String
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range
    Set c = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            unik = unik & "," & v
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
    unik = Mid(unik, 2)
End Function `

Comment: Ok.. Got it .. So have you tried `=SortArr(unik(Range),",",0)`  ... I tried; no error for dates. That's why I asked you date format in the formula bar. Enter a date in a cell and see the formula bar how it looks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216699/discussion-between-kiran-and-naresh-bhople).

Comment: yes for dates, we need to use datevalue. when comparing between arrays.... that resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad to hear that. .. edited the answer as well mentioning it s for dates. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Array of Dates in a String

- You only run the first `Sub`, the following 3 procedures are being
  called.
- The result is a 1D array containing the dates (as `Date`).
- The last `Sub` demonstrates how `Transpose` similarly to `Split`
  converts dates to strings. The same happens with the `ArrayList`.
  Additionally it shows how to copy the arrays to columns in a
  worksheet.

**How?**

- The `getDates` Sub  is calling the `getDatesFromString` Function which splits the string by `","` to the `Init` Array and further each of those new strings is split by `"-"` to the `Curr` Array.
- Then the values are written to the `Data` Array where each second value representing the month is calculated by calling the `getMonthENG3` function.
- Finally the array is being sorted by the `Sub` `sort1D` which uses the `QuickSort` algorithm and being passed to the variable `Data` in the initial `Sub` (`getDates`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getDates()
    Dim Result As String
    Result = "31-Dec-2020,24-Sep-2020,25-Mar-2021,02-Jul-2020,09-Jul-2020," _
           & "16-Jul-2020,30-Jul-2020,23-Jul-2020,27-Aug-2020,06-Aug-2020," _
           & "13-Aug-2020,20-Aug-2020,30-Dec-2021,29-Dec-2022,29-Jun-2023," _
           & "24-Jun-2021,30-Jun-2022"
    Dim Data() As Date: Data = getDatesFromString(Result)
    ' The result is a 1D array with the dates sorted ascending.
End Sub

Function getDatesFromString(ByVal InitString As String, _
                            Optional ByVal StringSeparator As String = ",", _
                            Optional ByVal DateSeparator As String = "-") _
         As Variant
    Dim Init() As String: Init = Split(InitString, StringSeparator)
    Dim Curr() As String, i As Long, Data() As Date: ReDim Data(UBound(Init))
    For i = 0 To UBound(Init)
        Curr = Split(Init(i), DateSeparator)
        Data(i) = DateSerial(CLng(Curr(2)), getMonthENG3(Curr(1)), CLng(Curr(0)))
    Next i
    sort1D Data, 0, UBound(Data)
    getDatesFromString = Data
End Function

Function getMonthENG3(ByVal Month3 As String) As Long
    Dim months As Variant
    months = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "" _
                 & "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    getMonthENG3 = Application.Match(Month3, months, 0)
End Function

Sub sort1D(Data As Variant, _
           Optional ByVal Lb As Long, _
           Optional ByVal Ub As Long)
    Dim Tmp As Variant, LO As Long, HI As Long, Piv As Long
    LO = Lb: HI = Ub: Piv = Data((Lb + Ub) \ 2)
    Do
        Do While (Data(LO) < Piv): LO = LO + 1: Loop
        Do While (Data(HI) > Piv): HI = HI - 1: Loop
        If (LO <= HI) Then
            Tmp = Data(LO)
            Data(LO) = Data(HI): Data(HI) = Tmp: LO = LO + 1: HI = HI - 1
        End If
    Loop While (LO <= HI)
    If (Lb < HI) Then sort1D Data, Lb, HI
    If (LO < Ub) Then sort1D Data, LO, Ub
End Sub

Sub writeDatesInvestigate()
    Dim Result As String
    Result = "31-Dec-2020,24-Sep-2020,25-Mar-2021,02-Jul-2020,09-Jul-2020," _
           & "16-Jul-2020,30-Jul-2020,23-Jul-2020,27-Aug-2020,06-Aug-2020," _
           & "13-Aug-2020,20-Aug-2020,30-Dec-2021,29-Dec-2022,29-Jun-2023," _
           & "24-Jun-2021,30-Jun-2022"
    Dim Data() As Date
    Data = getDatesFromString(Result)
    
    ' This shows that the data is formatted as Date (vbDate or 7).
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Debug.Print Data(j), VarType(Data(j))
    Next j
    
    ' This shows that Transpose transforms dates to strings (vbString or 8).
    Dim DataT() As Variant
    DataT = Application.Transpose(Data)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(DataT)
        Debug.Print DataT(i, 1), VarType(DataT(i, 1))
    Next i
  
    ' This shows how to copy the array to a 2D one-based one-column array.
    Dim DataR() As Date: ReDim DataR(1 To UBound(Data) + 1, 1 To 1)
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 0 To UBound(Data)
        DataR(k + 1, 1) = Data(k)
        Debug.Print DataR(k + 1, 1), VarType(DataR(k + 1, 1))
    Next k

    With [A1].Resize(UBound(DataT))
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        .Value = DataT
    End With
    With [B1].Resize(UBound(DataR))
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        .Value = DataR
        With .Offset(, 1)
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
            .Value = DataR
        End With
        With .Offset(, 2)
            .Clear
            .Value = .Offset(, -3).Value 'Formula = "=A1"
            .Value = DataR
        End With
        With .Offset(, 3)
            .Clear
            .NumberFormat = "DD-MMM-YYYY"
            .Value = .Offset(, -4).Value 'Formula = "=A1"
            .Value = DataR
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If one has Excel O365, you don't need to use an UDF. A possible solution (with your text in `A1`):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,PROPER(TEXT(SORTEREN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A6,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),,1),"dd-mmm-yyyy")))
```